# How to check doctrine transaction over several classes

Tags: doctrine

In my code I have to save several connected  entities. Some have a OneToMany relationship so I save these entities in another class. To be able to roll back the whole saving process I use transactions with doctrine.

in the class dealing with the "core" entity from which the other are depending I do the following:

```php
        $this->connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $this->entityManager->persist($report);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $this->entityManager->refresh($report);

            // call to connected entities
            $this->reportTopicManager->update($report, $reportDto);
            $this->imageUploader->uploadImages($report, $reportDto);

            $this->connection->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($this->connection->isTransactionActive()) {
                $this->connection->rollBack();
            }
            throw $e;
        }
```

**Do I have to do the same transaction check in the connected classes?** Or will everything rolled back, when I encounter an exception in the connected classes?

In another project I did, but then I always had to check additionally if a  transaction had already started, which raised the complexity of the code. So I wonder if this is necessary or if it is enough to have one transaction check around the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems to be necessary. If you don't do that you might run into this error, at least if you use the dama/doctrine-test-bundle for testing:

https://github.com/dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle/issues/58

The code now looks like this:

```php
        $selfOpened = false;
        $reportTopics = [];
        if (!$this->connection->isTransactionActive()) {
            $this->connection->beginTransaction();
            $selfOpened = true;
        }
        try {
            .... Do things....

                $reportTopics[] = $reportTopicDto;
            }
            if ($selfOpened) {
                $this->connection->commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($selfOpened) {
                $this->connection->rollBack();
            }
            $this->logError($e->getMessage());
            $message = 'We had boo boo. Didn't work';
            $message .= json_encode($reportTopicDto);
            throw new UnprocessableEntityHttpException($message, $e, 119);
        }
```